# GET a URL parameter with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to capture the lang variable and then translate the page based on this variable.

```
global $jwp_lang;
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo $url;
```

for example if the url contains http://localhost/about/**?lang=fr** I would like to capture this value.

Comment: echo `$_GET['lang']` ? output : `fr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily capture the value of lang variable using php Super Global variable [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)  :

```
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
echo $lang;
```

Comment: Sanchit Gupta don't you think it must be a comment. Oh come on.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to pass the URL parameters using add_query_var, and get the parameter using get_query_var.

Because, they can handdle the set, and get of multiple parameters, and is the recommended way of getting URL passed as parameters.